# how to generate new column values for each group using a condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in spark as follows:

`ID   Sales`

```
1      0  
1      0  
1      5000  
1      0    
1      0
1      2000
1      0
2      0
2      0
2      3000
2      1000
2      0
2      0
```

Now, I 'd like to create a third column that will, for each ID, start with 0 and increase by 1 whenever a strictly positive value is encountered in the Sales column. Whenever the indicator is increased by 1, I'd like that number to repeat until another strictly positive value is encountered for the Sales column down the rows.  The resulting dataframe would be as follows:

```
ID   Sales  Indicator
```

```
1      0      0  
1      0      0
1      5000   1
1      0      1
1      0      1
1      2000   2
1      0      2
2      0      0
2      0      0
2      3000   1
2      1000   2
2      0      2
2      0      2
```

How could I achieve this in an efficient way? Could we use mapPartitions for this? I looked into window functions but could not think of a way of doing it. Thank you very much.

Comment: How are you ordering data?  I mean, how do you know it is 0,0,5000,0,0,2000,0 and not 0,0,0,0,0,0,2000,5000?

Comment: say by date; but inherintly, that is not relevant

Answer (score 1):

Using Window functions, you could do it like this:

As Robert Horvick pointed out, you will need some way to order rows within a given ID, so that the result is deterministic.  Let's say you have a column `OrderingCol` that does this, so your data is something like:

```
ID   Sales    OrderingCol

1      0        1
1      0        2
1      5000     3
1      0        4
1      0        5
1      2000     6
1      0        7
2      0        1
2      0        2
2      3000     3
2      1000     4
2      0        5
2      0        6
```

Of course, as you say, any way of ordering the rows would work (by date, etc.).

Then, you could do something like this, assuming above data is in `df`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val ws = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("OrderingCol")
val df2 = df.withColumn("Indicator", sum(when($"Sales" > 0, 1).otherwise(0)).over(ws))
```